# Can I tell Castle Windsor to create a component in a separate AppDomain?

Tags: castle-windsor, appdomain

I've created a multi-threaded service that uses Castle Windsor to create components to run on separate threads. I Resolve an component by name with parameters for each thread.

I'm running into concurrency problems with a 3rd party library used by the components. I suspect that isolating those components in separate AppDomains will resolve the problem.

Is there a way to have Resolve create the component using a different AppDomain?

```
private ActivityThread NewActivityThread(ActivityInstance activityInstance)
{
    // Set up the creation arguments.
    System.Collections.IDictionary arguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    activityInstance.Parameters.ForEach(p => arguments.Add(p.Name, p.Value));

    // Get the activity handler from the container.
    IActivity activity = Program.Container.Resolve<IActivity>(activityInstance.Name, arguments);

    // Create a thread for the activity.
    ActivityThread thread = new ActivityThread(activity, activityInstance, _nextActivityID++);
    return thread;
}

public ActivityThread(IActivity activity, ActivityInstance instance, int id)
{
    _activity = activity;
    _instance = instance;
    _id = id;
}

public void Start()
{
    if (_thread == null)
    {
        // Create a new thread to run this activity.
        _thread = new Thread(delegate() { _activity.Run(); });
        _thread.Name = _activity.ToString();
        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want things in another *AppDomain*, instead of one component instance per thread? ( see PerThread in http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/lifestyles.html )

Comment: I'm trying to use AppDomains to isolate potentially harmful components from one another. For example, one uses a third-party library that instantiates a COM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already created a separate AppDomain, can't you just create a new instance of a Windsor container within the private AppDomain?

Answer (score 2):

Try the remoting facility. See:

- http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/remoting/index.html
- http://gojko.net/2008/07/09/really-simple-net-remoting-with-castle/